# How to autocomplete last name in magento 2 checkout?

Tags: magento2

What I mean is the following, that when the user writes in the first name field, a piece of data appears in the last name field.
For example, in the LayoutProcessor.php I can define the values that they are going to have, but it needs a trigger, and I would like to know if it is possible to autocomplete the surname field, when the name field has a value.

$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = 'Yone';
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['value'] = 'Dawnbringer';

Comment: Please explain in more detail

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that , but can i confirm is this your requirement = From the backend you will have the data according to which first name is entered you will provide the last name , if the first name maches the data then the last name should be auto-filled in the last name field , is that correct ? Is this what you are expecting to develop ?

Comment: Yes, that's right Mr. Khumar, could you please help me?